# Extract data from object hierarchy using Java Stream api

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Unable to use Stream to list of object hierarchies.
Here is the class diagram of the object I would like to retrieve data:

```
@Data
class Institution {
  private List<Orgs> org; 
}

@Data
class Orgs {
  private String orgName;
  private List<Employee> emp;
}

@Data
class Employee {
  private String id;
  private String name;
}

class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //I want to retrieve an employee name as "MARK"
        //I want to retrieve an employee name as "MARK" from OrgName as "BUSINESS"
        how would i acheive this??
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems you need to solve.

1. There can be more instances of `Orgs` with the `orgName` as `BUSINESS`
2. There can be more instances of  `Employee` with the `name` as `MARK`

It means, there can be 3 `Orgs` with such `orgName` and in **each** of them there are let's say 4 guys named as `MARK`.

Then the solution would vary depending on what do you want:

- **All** `MARK` employees from **all** `BUSINESS`-named organizations. Collect them all to a single horde. This is so far the easiest implementation:

  ```
  List<Employee> eachMarkFromEachBusiness = institution.getOrg()
       .stream()                                           // Stream<Orgs>
       .filter(org -> "BUSINESS".equals(org.getOrgName())) // Stream<Orgs>
       .flatMap(org -> org.getEmp().stream())              // Stream<Employee>
       .filter(emp -> "MARK".equals(emp.getName()))        // Stream<Employee>
       .collect(Collectors.toList());                      // List<Empoloyee>
  ```
- **All** `MARK` employees from the **first** `BUSINESS`-named organization found (in case you need a specific one, you need to include an additional filter based on ex. let's say VAT number or ID).

  ```
  List<Employee> eachMarkFromSingleBusiness = institution.getOrg()
       .stream()                                           // Stream<Orgs>
       .filter(org -> "BUSINESS".equals(org.getOrgName())) // Stream<Orgs>
       .findFirst()                                        // Optional<Orgs>
       .map(Orgs::getEmp)                                  // Optional<List<Employee>>
       .stream()                                           // Stream<List<Employee>>
       .flatMap(empList -> empList                         // Stream<Employee>
           .stream()                                       // .. Stream<Employee>
           .filter(emp -> "MARK".equals(emp.getName())))   // .. Stream<Employee>
       .collect(Collectors.toList());                      // List<Employee>
  ```
- **First** `MARK` employee from the **first** `BUSINESS`-named organization found. Again, if you want to be more specific than finding out the first one, you need to provide an additional filter **either** on the `Orgs` or `Employee` or **both**. Let the return type be `Optional` as long as no `MARK` or no `BUSINESS` can exist.

  ```
  Optional<Employee> singleMarkSingleBusiness = institution.getOrg()
       .stream()                                           // Stream<Orgs>
       .filter(org -> "BUSINESS".equals(org.getOrgName())) // Stream<Orgs>
       .findAny()                                          // Optional<Orgs>
       .map(Orgs::getEmp)                                  // Optional<List<Employee>>
       .stream()                                           // Stream<List<Employee>>
       .flatMap(empList -> empList                         // Stream<Employee>
           .stream()                                       // .. Stream<Employee>
           .filter(emp -> "MARK".equals(emp.getName())))   // .. Stream<Employee>
       .findFirst();                                       // Optional<Employee>
  ```

---

Note that `Optional::stream` method is available as of [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) and newer. As long as you have tagged [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), here is a workaround:

- [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) and newer:

  ```
  Stream<String> stream = new ArrayList<String>()         // List<String>
          .stream()                                       // Stream<String>
          .findFirst()                                    // Optional<String>
          .stream();                                      // Stream<String>
  ```
- [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8):

  ```
  Stream<String> stream = new ArrayList<String>()         // List<String>
          .stream()                                       // Stream<String>
          .findFirst()                                    // Optional<String>
          .map(Stream::of)                                // Optional<Stream<String>>
          .orElse(Stream.empty());                        // Stream<String>
  ```